# How do I upload/copy file to SharePoint Document Library with MetaData from C# client using NTLM authentication

Tags: spservices, ntlm

How do I create a c# console app that will run on a desktop, not on the SharePoint server, where I want to upload a word document, including some metadata, such as "Category" to a remote SharePoint server using the SharePoint Web Services having NTLM authentication, assuming my credentials (I have full rights on SharePoint Site Collection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Credit**

(much of this was derived from http://cecildt.blogspot.com/2010/10/upload-documents-to-sharepoint-2010.html - thanks Cecil!)

---

## **SharePoint Steps**

In SharePoint, create a new document library with a metadata field - call the metadata field "CustomMetaData1".  See implementation in method UploadFile below...

---

## **Visual Studio**

Create console app in Visual Studio.  Example assumes C#.

In the console app project, add the Service Reference to your SharePoint site (change values MyHost and MySite) - `http://MyHost/MySite/_vti_bin/copy.asmx`.  To work with my example code below, ensure the namespace of the Service Reference is set to SharePointWebService.

**App.config changes**

Before NTLM will work, we need to augment the security stuff in the app.config.  So, in the console app project, modify app.config - change...

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CopySoap" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

... to ...

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CopySoap">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Class and method for uploading a file to SharePoint**

In the console app project, add class with method for copying file.  I opted for a static method in this example.

***Summary of steps in method:***

- Get a reference to the web services client, and establish ClientCredentials.  This step may be optional because of the changes to the app.config binding section.
- Get the file name from the fully qualified file name/path.  SharePoint will need a file name to store the file as, and the original file name is as good as any name.
- Open the file, read in all the contents into a byte array.
- Construct the destination variable (SharePoint list URL appended with the file name).  Notice this is a string array?
- Create a metadata thingy (FieldInformation object).
- Create an OUT parameter variable.
- Call the web service method "CopyIntoItems"

**Class Definition**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using ConsoleApplication2.SharePointWebService;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class SharePointUtilities
    {
        public static void UploadFile(string SourceFilePathName, string SharePointListURI)
        {
            var wsClient = new SharePointWebService.CopySoapClient();
            if (wsClient.ClientCredentials != null)
            {
                wsClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            }

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(SourceFilePathName);

            var fileContentByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(SourceFilePathName);

            string[] fullyQualifiedDestination = { SharePointListURI + fileName };
            FieldInformation descInfo = new FieldInformation { DisplayName = "CustomMetaData1", Type = FieldType.Text, Value = "Test file for upload" };
            FieldInformation[] fileInfoArray = { descInfo };

            CopyResult[] arrayOfResults;

            uint result = wsClient.CopyIntoItems(fileName, fullyQualifiedDestination, fileInfoArray, fileContentByteArray, out arrayOfResults);
        }
    }
}
```

**Call the method from somewhere**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SharePointUtilities.UploadFile(@"c:\junk.file", "http://MyHost/MySite/MyList/");
        }
    }
}
```

Notes: The metadata on the Document List is populated by the array fileInfoArray.  If you need multiple metadata fields populated, you will need to add more than one FieldInformation object to the array fileInfoArray.  The property "DisplayName" is the metadata field name.  In practice, the call to the UploadFile method would likely need the ability to pass in the metadata values, so this example is a bit contrived, and brittle.  I wanted to present the most basic example, which I believe is presented.  Try/Catch and other best practices may be missing.  Use at your discretion.

Comment: Don't forget to select this as the answer so it doesn't keep showing up int he open question feed.

Comment: Ooops - sorry.  Just selected it...

Comment: No problem! We've all done it. It's easy to forget.